# Druid RabbitMQ Firehose

Tags: rabbitmq, druid

I'm trying to setup druid to work with rabbitmq firehose but getting the following error from Tranquility

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve type id 'rabbitmq' into a subtype of [simple type, class io.druid.data.input.FirehoseFactory]

I did the following
1. Installed Druid
2. Downloaded extension druid-rabbitmq
3. Copied druid-rabbitmq into druid extensions
4. Copied amqp-client jar to druid lib
5. Added druid-rabbitmq into druid.extensions.loadList in common.runtime.properties
6. In Tranquility server.json configuration added the firehose config

```
"ioConfig" : {
      "type" : "realtime",
      "firehose" : {
        "type" : "rabbitmq",
        "connection" : {
          "host": "localhost",
          "port": "5672",
          "username": "blackbox",
          "password": "blackbox",
          "virtualHost": "blackbox-vhost",
          "uri": "amqp://localhost:5672/blackbox-vhost"
        },
        "config" : {
          "exchange": "test-exchange",
          "queue" : "test-q",
          "routingKey": "#",
          "durable": "true",
          "exclusive": "false",
          "autoDelete": "false",
          "maxRetries": "10",
          "retryIntervalSeconds": "1",
          "maxDurationSeconds": "300"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: which version of Druid, Tranquility are you using?

Comment: I'm using imply 1.3.0 but I think Tranquility is for stream pushing while a firehose is used for stream pulling so I think this was the problem. So now I created a realtime node and it's running fine. I also had to copy lyra jar file into druid lib directory. Now I can publish data from rabbit and its been inserted into druid and I can query the data but problem is that in rabbit the message is still showing as unacked. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using imply 1.3.0 but I think Tranquility is for stream pushing while a firehose is used for stream pulling so I think this was the problem. So now I created a realtime node and it's running fine. I also had to copy lyra jar file into druid lib directory. Now I can publish data from rabbit and its been inserted into druid and I can query the data but problem is that in rabbit the message is still showing as unacked. Any idea?

Comment: Can you publish the final realtime spec? I'm trying to recreate something like this, and it would be incredibly helpful.